# How do I start a child process on Windows and capture its stderr?

Tags: windows, rust, child-process, stdio

I'm trying to write an integration test that starts my server, tickles it, and asserts on what it logs to `stderr` to pass or fail the test.

I'm using:

```
Command::new("stuff")
    .args(&[more, stuff])
    .stderr(/* XXX */)
    .spawn()
    .unwrap()
```

to start the server, where `XXX` has by turns been

1. `std::process::Stdio::piped()`,
2. a `std::fs::File` object, and
3. a raw something (handle or file descriptor) distilled from the `std::fs::File` object and converted `unsafe`ly into a `std::process::Stdio`.

All of these work fine under Linux (Ubuntu 16.04); none of them work under Windows.  In every case in Windows, when the test runs, I see a console window pop up and display the (correct) stuff from the server's `stderr` stream, but the pipe or the file remains empty and the assert times out waiting for data.

I think I've run out of ideas.  What should I be doing to make this test run under Windows?

Comment: Does redirecting the output of your server process work *outside* of Rust? I'm guessing that it's not Rust-related.

Comment: Sounds related to the Windows subsystem the app is compiled for. Here's an RFC that goes into this a bit https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1665-windows-subsystem.md